# List of generic structs / interfaces in Golang

Tags: go, generics

Is there a way to have a list of generic structs/interfaces in go?

Here is the thing I'm trying to achieve.

```golang
package main

type List[T any] struct {
    Elements []T
}

func (f *List[T]) Add(el T) {
    f.Elements = append(f.Elements, el)
}

type ListInterface[T any] interface {
    Add(el T)
}

func main() {
    listOfLists := make([]ListInterface[any], 0)
    listOfLists = append(listOfLists, &List[int]{})
}
```

Here is the error I get.

```
cannot use &List[int]{} (value of type *List[int]) as ListInterface[any] value in argument to append: *List[int] does not implement ListInterface[any] (wrong type for method Add)
    have Add(int)
    want Add(any)
```

So, if I understand this correctly, in go `any` is its own type. It's not a synonym to "any type you want at a runtime". My question is, is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: No is too short for an answer. Unless you make your ListInterface non-generic and let it take an any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do here suggests you're expecting go's generics to be type erasure (like Java generics are). They are not, however.

You have a `List[int]`, which means its `Add` method looks like this:

```
func (l *List) Add(el int) {
    l.Elements = append(l.Elements, el)
}
```

You then try to add this to a slice of objects that implement the interface:

```
Add(v any)
```

Now, you may think that an `int` can be used as `any`, and you're right, it can, but when you see:

```
var s []ListInterface[any]
```

You're saying that all elements in said slice will have an `Add` method that takes an argument of type `any`, which therefore means that:

```
s[0].Add("foo")
s[1].Add(123)
```

Should always be valid calls to make. If `s[0]` is of type `List[int]`, as is the case in your snippet, this doesn't hold true. You would be trying to append a string to `Elements` which is of type `[]int`.

There's an argument for saying that the inverse should be allowed:

```
s := []ListInterface[int]{}
s = append(s, &List[any]{})
```

Seeing as `List[any]` will accept an `int` argument, but this, too, isn't allowed. There's some cases where this could be useful, but there are plenty of cases where this could be problematic.

Essentially, generics in go are things handled at compile time. When you create a `List[int]`, the compiler will create a type like `List_int` and implement the `Add(el int)` method on that type, same as it will for any other `List` type you end up using. None of these types will have an `Add(any)` method, unless you create a `List[any]`. Think of it as compiler-assisted boiler plate code generation. Not runtime type erasure.

The result: `List[int]` and `List[any]` are completely distinct types, and therefore cannot sit side-by-side in a slice as though they are the same type. If you want to be able to do what you're trying to do, you could do something like this:

```
func (l *List[T]) AddAny(v any) {
    tv, ok := v.(T)
    if !ok {
        return // or return an error
    }
    l.Add(tv)
}
```

A method that takes an `any` value, use type assertions to see if the given value is compatible with the underlying type of the list, and add it if this is the case. Then you can add them to a single slice that would look like this:

```
type Lists interface {
    AddAny(any)
}

s := []Lists{}
s = append(s, &List[int]{}, &List[string]{})
s[0].AddAny(123) // will work
s[0].AddAny("foo") // will not, with the current code this will silently fail
s[1].AddAny("foo") // works fine
s[1].AddAny(123) // silently fails
```

But really, when you're doing things like this, the code just screams X-Y problem, where you're trying to use Y (generics) to solve your problem, whereas the real question is X: what is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you! Your answer (and summary in the comment below) helped me to understand how this all works and nudged me towards a possible solution.

Comment: I tried to find solution without dragging generics in, but it seems like I will have to do type assertion at some point. I just don't want to make this question more bloated with explanations of what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

- In your code, the `List[T]` struct is intended to implement the `ListInterface[T]` interface.
- When defining a variable with `ListInterface[T]` specifying a specific data type, the implementation should match that data type.
- However, in your code, you initialized a slice with the type `ListInterface[any]` and attempted to append an implementation with the data type `int` (`List[int]`).
- This results in a compilation error due to a type mismatch.
- Your requirement can be resolved with below code. You can remove the type variable from the `ListInterface` and implement the updated `Add` method.

```golang
package main

type List[T any] struct {
    Elements []T
}

func (f *List[T]) Add(anyElement any) {
    ele, ok := anyElement.(T) 
    if !ok {
        // Handle errors here, for example:
        // fmt.Println("Error: Type mismatch, cannot add element to the list."
        return
    }
    f.Elements = append(f.Elements, ele) 
}

type ListInterface interface {
    Add(ele any)
}

func main() {
    listOfLists := make([]ListInterface, 0)
    listOfLists = append(listOfLists, &List[int]{}, &List[string]{})
}
```

Comment: `listOfLists` is supposed to be able to hold any type of list. `*List[int]`, `*List[string]` etc.

Comment: See my answer, that implies that all values in the slice need to implement a method that takes `any`as an argument,. a `List[int]` only has an `Add(int)` method, a `List[string]` only has `Add(string)`, both of which are incompatible with `Add(any)`. The only way to have a slice with `List[int|string|...]` is to have `List`  explicitly implement a method that all implementations share (the `AddAny` from my example does this)

Comment: Updated the answer & will be helpful.